# Add Rich Text into QTextEdit Using Buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt5, I have some code which creates a button. I also have a QTextEdit Widget in which I type text. What I want is for every time I click the button, it allows me to add bold text to the QTextEdit, and if I click it agin, it stops adding bold text. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```py
#Import Module
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys

class AddToDeckWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddToDeckWindow, self).__init__()

        #Set The UI
        self.initUI()

        #Set The GUI Position And Size
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 900, 710)

        #Set The GUI Title
        self.setWindowTitle("Add")

        #Set The GUI Icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('give_way.png'))

        #Set The Translator
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        
    def initUI(self):

        #Set Font For The Bold Label Button
        boldFont = QFont()
        boldFont.setFamily(u"Corbel")
        boldFont.setPointSize(19)
        boldFont.setBold(True)
        boldFont.setWeight(75)

        #Create The Bold Label Button
        self.boldButton = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.boldButton.setText("B")
        self.boldButton.setFont(boldFont)
        self.boldButton.adjustSize()

        #Create The Text Box
        textBox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        textBox.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 200)

        #Set The Font
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        textBox.setFont(font)

#Create A Windows
def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = AddToDeckWindow()

    #Centers The Window On The Screen
    qtRectangle = win.frameGeometry()
    centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    win.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())


    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

This was my attempt to set the text to bold:

```py
def textBoldAddToDeck(self, eve):
        self.isBoldText = not self.isBoldText
        if self.isBoldText == True:
            self.editFrontTextAddMenu.insertHtml("<b>hi</b>")
        elif self.isBoldText == False:
            self.editFrontTextAddMenu.insertHtml("</b>")
        print(self.isBoldText)
```

This is the FULL Code (I know the variables are very long and I will change them soon.):

```python
#Import Module
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys

class AddToDeckWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AddToDeckWindow, self).__init__()

        #Set The UI
        self.initUI()

        #Set The GUI Position And Size
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1200, 946)

        #Set The GUI Title
        self.setWindowTitle("Add")

        #Set The GUI Icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('MainFlashcardAppIcon.png'))

        #Set The Translator
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        
    def initUI(self):
        widAddToDeckWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widAddToDeckWindow)

        ###DEFINE IS BOLD VARIABLE###
        self.isBoldText = False
        
        
        #Create A Label
        self.typeLabelAddMenu = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.typeLabelAddMenu.setText("Type")
        
        font_typeLabelAddMenu = QFont()
        font_typeLabelAddMenu.setPointSize(9)
        
        self.typeLabelAddMenu.setFont(font_typeLabelAddMenu)
        self.typeLabelAddMenu.adjustSize()

        self.typeButtonAddMenu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.typeButtonAddMenu.setText("Basic")
        #self.typeButtonAddMenu.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        self.deckLabelAddMenu = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.deckLabelAddMenu.setText("Deck")

        self.deckLabelAddMenu.setFont(font_typeLabelAddMenu)
        self.deckLabelAddMenu.adjustSize()
        
        self.deckButtonAddMenu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.deckButtonAddMenu.setText("Default")


        vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top.setSpacing(27)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top.addWidget(self.typeLabelAddMenu)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top.addWidget(self.typeButtonAddMenu, 1)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top.addWidget(self.deckLabelAddMenu)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top.addWidget(self.deckButtonAddMenu, 1)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_top.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        font_typeButtonAddMenu_setFont = QFont()
        font_typeButtonAddMenu_setFont.setPointSize(10)

        self.fieldButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.fieldButtonAddMenu_font.setText("Fields...")
        self.fieldButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(font_typeButtonAddMenu_setFont)

        self.cardsButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.cardsButtonAddMenu_font.setText("Cards...")
        self.cardsButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(font_typeButtonAddMenu_setFont)

        #Set Font For The Bold Label Button
        fontAddToDeckBold_setFont = QFont()
        fontAddToDeckBold_setFont.setFamily(u"Corbel")
        fontAddToDeckBold_setFont.setPointSize(19)
        fontAddToDeckBold_setFont.setBold(True)
        fontAddToDeckBold_setFont.setWeight(75)

        #Create The Bold Label Button
        self.textBoldButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textBoldButtonAddMenu_font.setText("B")
        self.textBoldButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckBold_setFont)

        #self.textBoldButtonAddMenu_font.mousePressEvent = self.textBoldAddToDeck  ##### CALL THE TEXT BOLD FUNCTION


        #Set Font For The Itallic Label Button
        fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont = QFont()
        fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont.setFamily(u"Corbel")
        fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont.setPointSize(19)
        fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont.setItalic(True)
        fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont.setBold(True)
        fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont.setWeight(75)

        #Create The Itallic Label Button
        self.textItallicButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textItallicButtonAddMenu_font.setText("I")
        self.textItallicButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckItallic_setFont)


        #Set Font For The Underline Label Button
        fontAddToDeckUnderline_setFont = QFont()
        fontAddToDeckUnderline_setFont.setFamily(u"Corbel")
        fontAddToDeckUnderline_setFont.setPointSize(19)
        fontAddToDeckUnderline_setFont.setUnderline(True)

        #Create The Underline Label Button
        self.textUnderlineButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textUnderlineButtonAddMenu_font.setText("U")
        self.textUnderlineButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckUnderline_setFont)


        #Set Font For The Superscript Label Button
        fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont = QFont()
        fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont.setFamily(u"Corbel")
        fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont.setPointSize(19)

        #Create The Subscript Label Button
        self.textSubButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textSubButtonAddMenu_font.setText("S<sub>2</sub>")
        self.textSubButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont)


        #Create The Superscript Label Button
        self.textSuperButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textSuperButtonAddMenu_font.setText("S<sup>2</sup>")
        self.textSuperButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont)


        #Create The Remove Formatting Label Button
        self.textRemoveFormatButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textRemoveFormatButtonAddMenu_font.setText("F<sub>x</sub>")
        self.textRemoveFormatButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont)


        #Create The Set Colour Label Button
        self.textSetColorButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textSetColorButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont)

        
        self.textSetColorButtonAddMenu_font.setStyleSheet(u"border :1px solid black;\n"
                                                            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                                            "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")

        self.textSetColorButtonAddMenu_font.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.textSetColorButtonAddMenu_font.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))


        #Create The Choose Colour Label Button
        self.textChooseColorButtonAddMenu_font = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textChooseColorButtonAddMenu_font.setFont(fontAddToDeckSuper_setFont)

        
        self.textChooseColorButtonAddMenu_font.setStyleSheet(u"border :1px solid black;\n"
                                                            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                                            "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.166 rgba(255, 255, 0, 255), stop:0.333 rgba(0, 255, 0, 255), stop:0.5 rgba(0, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.666 rgba(0, 0, 255, 255), stop:0.833 rgba(255, 0, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255));")

        self.textChooseColorButtonAddMenu_font.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.textChooseColorButtonAddMenu_font.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))

        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.setSpacing(16)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.fieldButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.cardsButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addStretch()
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textBoldButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textItallicButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textUnderlineButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textSubButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textSuperButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textRemoveFormatButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textSetColorButtonAddMenu_font)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.addWidget(self.textChooseColorButtonAddMenu_font)

        hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        

        self.editFrontTextAddMenu = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.editFrontTextAddMenu.setMinimumSize(800, 50)

        #Set The Font
        editFrontTextAddMenu_font = QFont()
        editFrontTextAddMenu_font.setPointSize(15)
        self.editFrontTextAddMenu.setFont(editFrontTextAddMenu_font)

        self.editBackTextAddMenu = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.editBackTextAddMenu.setMinimumSize(800, 80)

        #Set The Font

        self.editBackTextAddMenu.setFont(editFrontTextAddMenu_font)

        hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        #Create A Label
        self.FrontCardAddWindowLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.FrontCardAddWindowLabel.setText("Front")
        
        self.FrontCardAddWindowLabel.setFont(font_typeLabelAddMenu)
        self.FrontCardAddWindowLabel.adjustSize()

        #Create A Label
        self.BackCardAddWindowLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.BackCardAddWindowLabel.setText("Back")
        
        self.BackCardAddWindowLabel.setFont(font_typeLabelAddMenu)
        self.BackCardAddWindowLabel.adjustSize()

        hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.addWidget(self.FrontCardAddWindowLabel, 1, 1)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.addWidget(self.editFrontTextAddMenu, 2, 1)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.addWidget(self.BackCardAddWindowLabel, 3, 1)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.addWidget(self.editBackTextAddMenu, 4, 1)
        hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        #hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        #hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText.setRowStretch(14, 14)



        #Add The Horizontal Layouts To A Main Vertical Layout
        vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main.addLayout(hboxAddToDeckWindow_top)
        vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main.addLayout(hboxAddToDeckWindow_setFont)
        vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main.addLayout(hboxAddToDeckWindow_editFrontText)
        vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main.addStretch()
        

        widAddToDeckWindow.setLayout(vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main)

    def textBoldAddToDeck(self, eve):
        self.isBoldText = not self.isBoldText
        if self.isBoldText == True:
            self.editFrontTextAddMenu.insertHtml("<b>")
        elif self.isBoldText == False:
            self.editFrontTextAddMenu.insertHtml("</b>")
        print(self.isBoldText)

#Create A Windows
def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = AddToDeckWindow()

    #Centers The Window On The Screen
    qtRectangle = win.frameGeometry()
    centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    win.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())


    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

However, it didn't work.  Could anyone please help me

Comment: What is the relation between the two codes? What calls `editFrontTextAddMenu`? Where is `self.isBoldText` declared? Btw, I see that you're still *not* correctly using layouts and widgets in QMainWindow, I strongly suggest you to not ignore the matter.

Comment: The part was just a small snippet of the full code. I have editied the full code in now and I actually have used layouts (great advice! Thanks for it!)

Comment: For future reference, avoid pasting that much code. Examples should always be as minimal (but still reproducible) as possible. I know it isn't easy to reduce an example taken from a full program, but that's what *good posts* are (and what gives you higher possibility of upvotes). Questions with extensive examples are often just ignored, limiting the possibility of an answer. Does it take a lot of time? Yes, as it takes a lot of time to give you a good answer. Consider that good quality post usually require *hours* (even for answers!), but it's not for nothing, as it always pays in some way.

Comment: Then: 1) `vboxAddToDeckWindow_Main` should not be created with `self` as a parent (which automatically sets the layout to the argument widget): in this case, `self` is the main window, and setting a layout on a QMainWindow is forbidden; 2) don't use labels as buttons, unless absolutely necessary; in your case, to make things easier and avoid drawing icons, use a QToolButton, then set a simple QHBoxLayout to it, call `buttonLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`, then add the label to the layout with the proper alignment: `buttonLayout.addWidget(buttonLabel, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)`.

Comment: Okay. I'll make those changes right now. Thanks! And in the future, I will make sure that I avoid adding large amounts of code. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing to remember is that the rich text capabilities of Qt are partially limited and they *don't* comply with the *full* HTML standard.

Using `setHtml()` or `insertHtml()` does not exactly set/append the exact html used in the argument. The given html is parsed to a Qt compliant rich text segment and then merged to the underlying QTextDocument.

The result is clear if you try to print the output of `toHtml()`, which will not be the same as what you used. Here is the output of `toHtml()` before appending the bold text (I skipped the headers):

```
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; 
-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">not bold</p>
```

And here is after using `insertHtml("<b>bold</b>")`:

```
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; 
-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">not bold</p>
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; 
-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">
<span style=" font-weight:600;">bold</span></p>
```

As you can see, there's no trace of the `<b>` tag, which is converted to a `<span>` instead.

In your case, what happens is that a simple `<b>` is just ignored, since it has no valid contents: while Qt is smart enough to close tags that have been left open, there was no text, so nothing was actually added to the document.

The correct solution is actually more simple, as QTextEdit already provides some functions to change the format at the current cursor position (as explained in the [Using QTextEdit as an Editor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#using-qtextedit-as-an-editor) section of the documentation), including [`setFontWeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setFontWeight):

```
        if self.isBoldText == True:
            self.editFrontTextAddMenu.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        elif self.isBoldText == False:
            self.editFrontTextAddMenu.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Normal)
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand now! Thanks so much @musicamante!